# Having issues returning an XML page with ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, get

I am having issues with the .ajax call:

```
    $("#search").click(function()
    {
        $.ajax(
        {
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://www.omdbapi.com/",
            data: { s : "True", r: "XML"},
        //  dataType: "XML",
            success:function(result)
            {
                $("#DBSearch").html(result);
            }
        });
    });
```

S is the movie to search and r is the return type.
When using fiddler, I can see the request coming back fine, but it is not displaying anything in my browser.

I'm also getting a TypeError: e is null in firefox debugger.
Here is the html:

```
<div id="DBSearch"> 

</div>
<button id="search">Search Movie</button>
```

The sample query results returns in fiddler:

```
 <root response="True">
    <Movie Title="True Grit" Year="2010" imdbID="tt1403865" Type="movie"/>
    <Movie Title="True Lies" Year="1994" imdbID="tt0111503" Type="movie"/>
    <Movie Title="Dodgeball: A True Underdog Story" Year="2004" imdbID="tt0364725" Type="movie"/>
    <Movie Title="True Romance" Year="1993" imdbID="tt0108399" Type="movie"/>
    <Movie Title="True Blood" Year="2008" imdbID="tt0844441" Type="series"/>
    <Movie Title="True Grit" Year="1969" imdbID="tt0065126" Type="movie"/>
    <Movie Title="True Crime" Year="1999" imdbID="tt0139668" Type="movie"/>
    <Movie Title="Dreamer: Inspired by a True Story" Year="2005" imdbID="tt0418647" Type="movie"/>
    <Movie Title="One True Thing" Year="1998" imdbID="tt0120776" Type="movie"/>
    <Movie Title="True Legend" Year="2010" imdbID="tt1425257" Type="movie"/>
    </root>
```

Comment: ... Why are you doing `.html(result)` if `result` is *XML*? is this a cross-domain request?

Comment: I'm not certain on the question. I assumed that it would set the div's html content to that result of the call.

Comment: The problem is not all xml is valid as html, therefore if you try to do .html(xmlstring) or .html(xmldoc) you will likely get inconsistent or unexpected results because the browser will try to append it as HTML rather than XML.

Comment: Would I need to parse the data as xml for the browser to read this correctly when loading into the div? I apologize, I am really new to jquery and web programming in general

Comment: Can you show an example of the xml? likely you'll need to parse the xml and generate your own html to insert.

Comment: *"Is this a cross-domain request?"*

Comment: I believe it is. The url is a open source db api.

Comment: In that case, is said api correctly implementing CORS? If it isn't, then you won't be able to do this without the help of server-side code.

Comment: That I am not certain. If I just return it as text I can get the data fine. I may need to parse it from there.

Comment: If you can get the data as text and output that to your html, then yes, it is implementing CORS correctly.

Comment: I guess my question now is, is there a way to display this as XML or do I have to parse the text to accomplish what a browser does automatically with a form?

Comment: Is it correct to say you've answered your own question?  Looks like the API returns JSON for you which is a much saner format to parse with your javascript.  Don't use `eval` to evaluate the JSON, use `JSON.parse(result)`.  If you've answered your own question you should post it as an answer.

Comment: Updated with your suggest nzifnab. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Read on the api and it default returns to JSON.

```
success:function(result)
{
    var obj = eval("(" + result + ")");
    $("#DBSearch").html(obj.Search[0].Title);
}
```

This was a much easier solution.
Even better:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(result);
```

Thank you nzifnab and KevinB